# Attach-focus not working in aurelia-dialog

Tags: aurelia, aurelia-dialog

I have the following:

```
<ai-dialog>
    <ai-dialog-header style="display:flex;justify-content:space-between">
        <span>New Person</span>
        <i class="fa fa-close" style="cursor:pointer" click.delegate="controller.cancel()"></i>
    </ai-dialog-header>

    <ai-dialog-body>
        <div style="display:flex;flex-grow: 1">
            <div class="field">
                <div class="field-title">First Name</div>
                <div class="field-value">
                   <input style="flex-grow:1" type="text" attach-focus="true" value.bind="criteria.firstName & validate" />
                </div>
            </div>
            ....
        </div>
     </ai-dialog-body>

     <ai-dialog-footer>
         ...
     </ai-dialog-footer>
```

When the dialog is displayed, I'm expecting first name input box to have focus but nothing has focus -- I manually have to click in the box to set focus.

Any thoughts?

Comment: One tiny possibility is that attach-focus doesn't work if you have developer console open and active, since the focus jumps to the console log input.

Comment: Thanks, tried closing the console and still no magic.

Comment: Hmm, unable to reproduce. https://gist.run/?id=e92d59f39898802e6fdaa6f1644845a5

Comment: Always worth asking, do you have the latest repositories? Do you have any other custom attributes messing things up? Can you create a new skeleton project and reproduce the issue there? Could the flex style be causing some weird focus issues (it's a slim possibility)? Could the `validate` binding on your `value` be causing issues?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following: **focus.bind="true"**

```
<input style="flex-grow:1" type="text" focus.bind="true"...
```

You could also make the focus depending on the model what you didn't need here.

Here are more details:
http://aurelia.io/blog/2015/06/05/building-aurelias-focus-attribute/